# Pentaho DI default logging database for kitchen.sh

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I am using PDI 8.3 with repo database in another server.

In my expectation, if I do not define any log connections in the job properties, the job will not send any logs to the repo database.

However, when I run a job with kitchen.sh, it defines new database connection "live_logging_info" that points to "localhost:5432". Because PDI repo database is in another server, the job fails.

May I know how to define the default DB log connection? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under PDI 8.3 there should be a folder called simple-jndi.  Within that folder there should be a file called jdbc.properties.    In that file near the bottom there are settings for live_logging_info.   By default it points to localhost:5432 but you can set it to any location. Or it can be another type of database (MySQL,MSSQL, etc).
The settings that are available by default are:

live_logging_info/type=javax.sql.DataSource
live_logging_info/driver=org.postgresql.Driver
live_logging_info/url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernate?searchpath=pentaho_dilogs
live_logging_info/user=hibuser
live_logging_info/password=password